# Can Firebase Storage rules validate against Realtime Database data?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I've seen from this post (https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/09/announcing-cross-service-security-rules) that you can validate Storage rules against Firestore data, however, I can't find any information if you can do it for Realtime Database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Riiight at the bottom of the post, the last paragraph says:

> So there you have it. That’s our shiny new feature. Try it out and let
> us know what you think. For the next milestone, we plan to support
> cross-service rules queries to the Realtime database! Stay tuned!

So.. not yet :)